# Power saving enabled after upgrade

Tags: 12.04

Recently we've upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and the monitor goes on energy saving (and wakes when there's any input (mouse/keyboard)). However, the odd thing is, that it's completely disabled in the system settings. It's set to 'Never' in 'Brightness and lock' and suspend is disabled in 'Power'.

I've also tried `sudo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false` and `sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false` but the monitor still goes to energy saving within 10 minutes of inactivity.

This has *probably* todo with the upgrade, as it didn't before. Do you have any idea what can be done to solve this?

**Edit**

Seems when I have a Chrome window in full screen (F11) the screen doesn't turn off.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I too have had issues with Suspend -- my resume remains on a black screen.
The best and fastest method for a fix is to report a bug.

Instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs 
You'll need a Launchpad acount: https://launchpad.net/